# Row Rearrangement Based on Cell Matching

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA script for a worksheet in Excel and facing challenges. The script's goal is to rearrange rows based on matching cell values, and I would appreciate any help or insights.

Objective:
The script should:

1. Identify rows in a specific column (let's say column C) where cell values match a pattern "C####" (C followed by four digits).
2. For each matching value in this column, find a corresponding row in another column (column D) with the same value.
3. Rearrange the sheet so each row with the "C####" value in column C is directly above the row with its matching value in column D.
4. Ignore all values that don't match this pattern, including various non-relevant strings and numeric values, as well as blank cells.

Challenges:
The script partially works – it successfully processes a significant portion of the rows but doesn't complete the task for all. Below is the critical part of the script (i think):

```vb
' ... [initialization code]

For i = 2 To lastRow
    cellValue = Application.Clean(Trim(ws.Cells(i, "C").Value))
    
    If cellValue Like "C####" Then
        ' Logic to find the matching value in column D and rearrange rows
        ' ...
    End If
Next i

' ... [cleanup and finalization code]
```

Specific Questions:

1. How can I modify the script to ensure all relevant rows are matched and rearranged correctly?
2. Are there optimizations or changes you'd recommend for improving accuracy and efficiency?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

This is the closest i have come to getting it to work. It does about 1000 rows, but not all of them.

```
Sub RearrangeRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") ' Replace with your actual sheet name

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim matchRow As Variant
    Dim i As Long, rowCounter As Long
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    rowCounter = 2

    While rowCounter <= lastRow
        cellValue = Application.Clean(Trim(ws.Cells(rowCounter, "C").Value))
        
        If cellValue Like "C####" And Not dict.exists(cellValue) Then
            dict.Add cellValue, Nothing
            matchRow = Application.Match(cellValue, ws.Range("D1:D" & lastRow), 0)
            
            If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
                If rowCounter <> matchRow Then
                    ws.Rows(rowCounter).Cut
                    ws.Rows(matchRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "No match for cell value: " & cellValue
            End If
        End If

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox "Rows rearranged based on matching patterns."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving rows around can be tricky - this worked for me, starting from the bottom and looking in ColD, and finding matches in ColC:

```vb
Sub RearrangeRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, m, rwMatch As Range, cellValue As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") ' Replace with your actual sheet name
    'start with last row, looking at ColD
    Set rw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).EntireRow
    
    Do While rw.Row > 2
        
        cellValue = Application.Clean(Trim(rw.Columns("D").Value))
        If cellValue Like "C####" Then
            'match in C?
            m = Application.Match(cellValue, ws.Columns("C"), 0)
            
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'need to do anything? Match not on same row, or on row above
                If rw.Row <> m And rw.Row <> m + 1 Then
                    Set rwMatch = ws.Rows(m) 'get a reference to the row *before* the Insert
                    rw.Insert
                    rwMatch.Copy rw.Offset(-1) 'don't cut: moves the reference
                    rwMatch.Delete
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "No match for cell value: " & cellValue
            End If
        End If

        Set rw = rw.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```